# How does +1 damage interact with a power with two damage types?

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

Consider a power like the Legacy's "Galvanize":

> Until the start of your next turn, increase damage dealt by hero targets by 1.

How does this interact with powers that deal two different types of damage, such as Fanatic's "Exorcism":

> Fanatic deals 1 target 1 melee damage and 1 radiant damage.

Does Fanatic deal 2 melee damage and 2 radiant damage? Or 2 of one type and 1 of another type of the player's choice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It increases damage dealt by hero's each time they deal damage so in this case Fanatic would deal 1 target 2 melee damage and 2 radiant damage. It should be remembered that in a case like Fanatic each hit if the damage is considered a different damage. And in the case of Legacy it increases all hero damage.

Now where you need to be careful is if you where dealing with something that said the next time the character did damage or the first time that turn they do damage in a case like that only the melee portion of the damage would be increased.

This is how the it works in the iPad app when using Fanatic's power while Legacy's power is in effect.